# Spring boot setting included profiles via environment variables

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am wondering has anyone else noticed this issue when using Spring Boot 2.0.3. In my application.properties, I have set the spring.profiles.active to the global profiles I will use. Then, depending on the environment being deployed to, I set spring.profiles.include in the environment variables. However, when the application runs, it only picks up the profiles specified with the include property. So

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=http
```

**environment**

```
spring.profiles.include=dev
```

Results in

*2018-08-09 13:45:35.025  INFO [main] Application : The following profiles are active: dev*

Instead of

*2018-08-09 13:45:35.025  INFO [main] Application : The following profiles are active: dev,http*

If both properties (spring.profiles.active and spring.profiles.include) are set in the same place, this works fine. This seems like a bug to me, or am I doing something stupid?

From what I understand, Spring will go through each of it's property sources until it finds the property - this doesn't appear to be happening here.

Comment: I indeed manage to reproduce your behavior. But then, what is your question ? It's easily worked around by using `spring.profile.include` in your properties

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is I need to set the include property at runtime based on the deployment - this is then used to load deployment environment specific properties based on the active profiles. Just seems weird that they clash like this.

Comment: I understand and I do that too. The only difference is that in my properties, i use include rather than active. I've been doing so for years. I think (IIRC) it was because active was getting overriden (not unlike your issue).

Comment: I noticed that as well - there have been a few issues around the order in which active/included profiles are loaded, which makes me think that this behaviour is a bug, or just something very, very, very stupid I am doing :)

Comment: It's probably a bug, to me, the documentation predicts the behavior you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** : don't use `spring.profiles.active` : it's not exactly what you believed it is.

---

**Long version**

Uuum, I tried to debug a bit how the profiles were loaded in spring-boot :

To mimic your case, I put a

- `spring.profiles.include=dev` in my **environment**
- `spring.profiles.active=demo` in my **application.yml**

I reached `ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader` and that's where the magic happens :

During `initializeActiveProfiles()` ,the loader looked for the `spring.profiles.active` in my **environment** (because environment takes precedence over properties) and then `spring.profiles.include` (still in the environment). It then activated the profile(s) found, in my case `dev`.

Afterwards, it tries to load subsequent profiles from its propertySources, where it indeed finds `spring.profiles.active=dem`...

**BUT**, in `maybeActivateProfiles()`, it happens that `this.activatedProfiles` is set to true (duh, `dev` had already been activated), and thus, `demo` is voluntarily not activated.

My take on this is that `spring.profiles.active` is **ONLY** used (as a switch) to activate the first profile(s) and then, only `include` applies. The funny thing here is that `include` takes precedence over `active` when it is found in a document with greater priority.

Comment: After debugging through it myself I see what you mean - I'm sure there is a reason for doing it this way, but it seems a bit over complicated to me! I think the best approach for me would be just setting all profiles in either spring.profiles.active or spring.profiles.include at runtime

Comment: What do you mean by a "document with higher priority"??

Comment: I mean that properties get loaded in a specific order : first, application.properties, then application-profile.properties in the same order as the profiles. Every property defined in a later document will override the former. Thus, application-dev's `spring.profiles.active` will override application.properties's `spring.profiles.active`. The (kinda) unexpected thing here, is that `spring.profile.include` defined in application.properties still overrules `spring.profile.active` in a later document.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe it's not the nicest solution but you can enumerate ALL the profiles in the environment variables:

```
spring.profiles.active=http, dev
```

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking this might be the best way since Spring doesn't seem to be able to correctly parse the profiles if they are set in different sources!